# Network flow balancing constraint in R

Tags: r, linear-programming

I am a bit lost getting started with a minimum cost flow problem in R. In my mind the restriction below is a "classic" (sum of inputs minus sum of outputs equals a demand-supply-vector) and should not be hard to find - in a sparse notation (I would like to avoid a transition matrix like here: [Minimum Cost Flow - network optimization in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43616480/minimum-cost-flow-network-optimization-in-r) ). My question is, how can this flow balance restriction be implemented in R or is there a coding example that I overlooked?

[image]

Comment: Sorry your question is not completely clear to me. You want to avoid the creation of a full matrix, am I right ?... does the use of a sparse matrix solve your issue ? (for example Rsymphony supports sparse matrices...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think there are modelling approaches which allow to "slice" this specific constraint. On the other hand, I think using a sparse matrix would help. I have to try that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of minimum cost flow using igraph and Rsymphony with sparse matrix (slam package) :

Given this input :

```
library(igraph)
nodes <- data.frame(name=paste0("N",1:8),
                    supply=c(10,20,0,-5,0,0,-15,-10))

edges <- data.frame(nodefrom = paste0("N",c( 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7)),
                    nodeto   = paste0("N",c( 4, 1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8)),
                    cost     = c( 2, 1, 0, 6, 1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9),
                    capacity = c(15,10,10,10, 5,10,10,20,15,10,15),
                    name     = paste0("E",1:11))
G <- graph.data.frame(edges)
V(G)$supply <- nodes$supply[match(V(G)$name,nodes$name)]
# plot the graph
set.seed(3)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(G, vertex.size=30,
     vertex.label=paste0(V(G)$name,' (',V(G)$supply,')'),
     vertex.color='lightblue', edge.arrow.size=0.5,
     edge.label=paste0(E(G)$name,' (',E(G)$cost,',',E(G)$capacity,')')
     )
```

[image: Input Graph]

```
library(Rsymphony)
library(slam)

nVars <- ecount(G)
obj <- E(G)$cost
bounds <- list(upper=list(1:nVars,E(G)$capacity),lower=list(1:nVars,rep(0,nVars)))
types <- rep('C',ecount(G))

mat <- simple_triplet_zero_matrix(nrow=nrow(nodes),ncol=nrow(edges))
colnames(mat) <- E(G)$name
rownames(mat) <- V(G)$name
rhs <- -V(G)$supply
dir <- rep('==',vcount(G))
for(v in V(G)){
  outEdges <- E(G)[from(v)]$name
  inEdges <- E(G)[to(v)]$name
  mat[v,match(inEdges,colnames(mat))] <- 1
  mat[v,match(outEdges,colnames(mat))] <- -1
}

output <- Rsymphony_solve_LP(obj=obj,
                   mat=mat,
                   dir=dir,
                   rhs=rhs,
                   bounds=bounds,
                   types=types,
                   max=FALSE,
                   write_lp = TRUE)

# plot the solution
set.seed(3)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(G, vertex.size=30,
     vertex.label=paste0(V(G)$name,' (',V(G)$supply,')'),
     vertex.color='lightblue', edge.arrow.size=0.5,
     edge.label=paste0(E(G)$name,' flow = ',output$solution))
```

[image: Output Graph]

About the sparse matrix, here we use `simple_triplet_zero_matrix` that creates a matrix with all zeros (and occupies basically no memory, since in sparse matrices only non-zeros are stored) of size nrow x ncol and then we replace some indices with some non-zero coefficients.

Probably in case of huge inputs, this might be not really efficient.
It's probably more efficient to use the function `simple_triplet_matrix(i,j,v)` where `i,j,v` are 3 vectors of the same length indicating the non-zero coefficients; in particular `i` are the row indexes, `j` are the column indexes and `v` are the non-zero coefficients at position `i,j`.

Comment: This is so useful. Thanks again.